# Creating dimension feature class that displays inches in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, dimensions

I have a line feature class in State Plane survey feet. When I create a dimension feature class I simply cannot figure out how to get the dimension to display inches. There seems to be a button for inputting an expression (DimLenght*12 maybe), but it is greyed out. There is an option to set the display output to inches, but that doesn't seem to affect the final output - the dimension lines still show feet, but with an " suffix (I set this option).

Where is the option to change what is displayed on the dimension line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you would like the lengths to show 120 inches as opposed to 10 ft.

There is currently no way to simply change the display of a dimension feature class label to show feet and inches.

This is going to be fixed in the next updates.

Comment: I wound up figuring out how to enter an expression to genereate custom text display: Round([DimLength]*12), 0) + " \"" gave me 120" rather than 10 feet. Worked OK.

Comment: @ThatIdiot could you please share how you were able to change the expression of the Dimension class labels?